# Running a 32 bit .NET application on 64 bit machine

Tags: .net, 32bit-64bit

I have an application with projects having Platform as Any CPU. when run the application on 64 bit machine(win7) in VS2008 I can see in task manager process with *32 which means its running in 32 bit mode. But I have read that applications with Platform as Any CPU run according to the machine(64 bit in my case) . I am all confused. Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the project that creates the actual executable is set to `AnyCPU` and not `x86`? This project as well as all the referenced projects should be set to `AnyCPU`. If you do that the process will run as a 64 bit process on 64 bit Windows (and as a 32 bit process on 32 bit Windows).

It is the platform target for the .EXE project that determines the "bitness" of the application. If any referenced .DLL project has a "bitness" that is incompatible with the "bitness" of the running application you will get a runtime error. E.g. if an `AnyCPU` .EXE project references a `x86` .DLL project it will succesfully run on 32 bit Windows but fail with a runtime error on 64 bit Windows.

---

The question is about Visual Studio 2008 but Visual Studio 2012 with .NET 4.5 introduced the [anycpu32bitpreferred setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zekwfyz4(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **anycpu32bitpreferred** compiles your assembly to run on any platform. Your application runs in 32-bit mode on systems that support both 64-bit and 32-bit applications. You can specify this option only for projects that target the .NET Framework 4.5.

Turning this setting on (the default in Visual Studio) means that `AnyCPU` applications will execute as 32 bit even on a 64 bit operating system.

Comment: All projects are set to AnyCPU along with the platform target of .EXE project . But my application is running in 32 bit mode as shown in task manager . Also , its failing because its failing to access 32 bit DSN of IBM DB2 Server Client at runtime as you said.

Comment: @nishantv: The documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zekwfyz4.aspx. It seems that either the documentation is wrong our there is something in your end that you have overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

As VS2008 is 32 bit I would expect it to launch a 32 bit process as well. Another reason could be you're referencing 32-bit only DLLs?

Have you tried running the application outside VS2008 - is it still in 32 bit mode?

Comment: yes all dlls are also 32 bit . I am also accessing IBM Data Server client v9.5.3 but I am getting  "Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider. " . I am trying to work around this problem which I was thinking is due to 32 bit-64 bit conflict . Do you have any idea about this

Comment: Well, if you reference DLLs that are 32-bit (not AnyCPU or X64), then the application will be run in 32-bit mode, as you can not use 32-bit DLLs in a 64-bit application and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Build => Configuration Manager
2. Click Active Solution Platform dropdown list and select .
3. In Type or select the new platform dropdown list, select 'x64'.
4. Hit OK.

Comment: Any CPU is just as good - it should run the application in 64-bit mode on 64-bit systems and in 32-bit mode on 32-bit systems. Unless you reference something that forces the application into 32-bit mode. Making it 64-bit only prevents it from running on a 32-bit system.

Comment: @Mayur I did what you said but selected x86 . My application is now running successfully on 64 bit machine accessing 32 bit dsn using vs2008 . My question is do I have to do this for all applications manually in order to work ? What is the general solution?

Comment: An application specifically compiled for X86 can't run in 64-bit mode - there must be some confusion here...